# PHP Variable Spacing Error

Tags: php, row, echo, space

I am having an issue with a php variable not including rows that contain spaces. I have it so the user can easily delete something from their list by clicking the x button on the page. The x button contains the link used to delete the item. The issue is the php variable "Item" seems to not fully include items with spaces. If a user click to delete Car Oil then url would become "http://www.example.com/delete.php/?Item=Car". It does not add the space with the rest of the word to allow it to be deleted from the list. Also if I echo the variable $Item it fully has everything so it would it would display Car Oil. Any help would be loved.

```
$query = mysql_query("select Items, Loc from Members where Username = '$Username' and Session = '$Session'ORDER BY Loc+0 ASC, Items ASC;");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
$Item = $row['Items'];
echo "<p1>";
echo $row['Items'], ' - Aisle ' .$row['Loc'];
echo "<a href=http://www.example.com/delete.php/?Item=$Item><img src=http://exmample.com/Images/x.png style='margin-bottom:-5px;'></a>";
echo "</p1>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might need to [urlencode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) the value on your html. For instance

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/delete.php/?Item=<?php echo urlencode($itemName); ?>">
     click here to delete
</a>
```

Comment: Sorry but it is surrounded by php already. So I can't have php in php. Your solution is very good. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Space is not a valid character in a url

Look at [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

```
echo "<a href=http://www.example.com/delete.php/?Item=".urlencode($Item)."><img src=http://exmample.com/Images/x.png style='margin-bottom:-5px;'></a>";
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks for the quick response.